# Is it possible purely via Javascript to detect whether the user's eyes are looking at an element?

Tags: javascript, eye-tracking

The closest thing I've found is Text 2.0 but that requires a browser plugin.  Can it be done without needing the user to download a plugin?

Comment: wouldn't you need some sort of hardware to make that work?  a webcam, at minimum, and how would you control different manufacturer cameras on different platforms from within a browser without a plugin?

Comment: You're talking about getting access to a camera or webcam, getting snapshots of data from the camera and then doing image processing on that data in javascript to try to identify eyes and where they were pointed.

Comment: Eye tracking isn't necessarily difficult with the right library, but there is no way you'll ever get access to the camera from javascript.  You can't even write or read local files let alone access peripherals.

Comment: Only thing i could think of doing this in javascript is by intelligently assuming at what part of the page the user is most likely looking at. 

Facebook does this with videos. Maybe you have noticed that at somepoint when you scroll the vids start playing.

Comment: @headCode - Huh? What do you mean by `"there is no way you'll ever get access to the camera from javascript"`. I've played an on-screen xylophone on a webpage simply by waving my hands about. I merely had to accept the prompt telling me that the page wanted access to my camera. Access to cameras from JS has been available for a couple of years now.

Comment: Andrew Counts, HeadCode, MaxBumaye: good for you that comments cannot be downvoted. One can easily access the webcam in modern browsers using [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC)...

Comment: Eye tracking was implemented in certain samsung android phones in order to detect whether the user was looking at the screen. This ability was accomplished due to the fact that there was a perfect relative positioning between the camera and screen that could give reliable calculations to determine where the user was looking. Good luck trying to do the same thing without that perfect relativity. Disregarding that I believe javascript is way to slow for that kind of image processing.

Comment: Thanks enhzflep &  LJ_1102.  Sheesh, no need to break my balls over a legitimate question.  You can do some pretty amazing things via JavaScript these days, people.  Hell, if you can play [Quake 3](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quakejs.com%2F&ei=-MVyVPvzOaScigKOhYGABg&usg=AFQjCNGtFEcUMtLUcsp4X-EAFkiVVCYeeA&sig2=lHYHg6AxhPNLf498QDwWxg&bvm=bv.80185997,d.cGE&cad=rja) in a browser, I don't see what you naysayers are moaning about.

Also, obviously you will need a webcam.  I realise the accuracy isn't going to be perfect.